# frequency data occurs in the table

Tags: excel

I want to know if it is a possiblility to find the frequency string data occurs in the table which contain strings. I find there is a `FREQUENCY` function, but it is to find the frequency numeric data occurs between some specific values.

For example, I have the table:

http://img17.imageshack.us/img17/8405/excelc.jpg

And want to know how many times in first column (ID number of product) appears each of product (ABC1, ABC2, CD3, G5, FG4).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could easily do that with a pivot table !

Comment: I try to do this with pivot table but i have a problem with correct create this kind of table :/ or maybe i do it wrong cause... in first table "ABC1" occurs three times so in pivot table i supposed to see 3 times frequency, but it create sum total of "ABC1" and show me nine occurs :/

Answer (score 1):

Not tested, but you'll need the `COUNTIF` function. Try something like the following for row 2 and just fill it down (I believe the syntax is correct):

```
=COUNTIF($A$2:$A$65535, $A2)
```

Subsequent rows should be filled as

```
=COUNTIF($A$2:$A$65535, $A3)
=COUNTIF($A$2:$A$65535, $A4)
=COUNTIF($A$2:$A$65535, $A5)
.
.
.
```

Comment: Tnx lc! Syntax is almost perfect ;) but it is possible to find only UNIQUE data, cause when it show me frequency of occurs data "ABC1" three times, when i want ones ... ?

Comment: @netmajor It would help if you gave an example of exactly what output you're expecting. If I'm understanding correctly now, what you want is not a column of how many rows include the product ID, but actually the pivot table, as @Patrick Honorez is suggesting above. This would give you one row for each unique product.

Comment: Yes yes , i must do some example to see that, bu it works at last ;)